# Returning Jersey Response vs Customized POJO Class Object

Tags: java, jax-rs, pojo, jersey-1.0

I am little confused to decide which way is better that, in jersey we can return Response object(jax-rs) and also customized pojo class object.I dont know which way is better and why.can anybody suggest? Please note the return types in both the cases.Here are my two cases.

case 1:

```
@POST
    @Path("/authentication")
    public AuthenticationResponse authenticate(@NotNull FITransXTRequest objFITransXTRequest) {
        logger.debug("## entering authenticate method");

        System.out.println(objFITransXTRequest);
        AuthenticationResponse objAuthResponse = new AuthenticationResponse();
        JsonObject objResult = objAuthentication.authenticate(objFITransXTRequest);
        System.out.println(objFITransXTRequest);
        if (objResult != null) {
            objAuthResponse.setStan(objResult.get("stan").getAsString());
            objAuthResponse.setErrorMessage(objResult.get("responseMsg").getAsString());
            objAuthResponse.setStatus(objResult.get("responseCode").getAsString());
            objAuthResponse.setUidNumber(objResult.get("uidNumber").getAsString());
            objAuthResponse.setRrn(objResult.get("rrn").getAsString());
            objAuthResponse.setRdt(objFITransXTRequest.getDt());
        }
        return objAuthResponse;
    }
```

case 2:

```
 @POST
    @Path("/authentication")
    public Response authenticate(FITransXTRequest objFITransXTRequest) {
        AuthenticationResponse objAuthResponse = new AuthenticationResponse();
        JsonObject objResult = objAuthentication.authenticate(objFITransXTRequest);
        System.out.println(objFITransXTRequest);
        if (objResult != null) {
objAuthResponse.setStan(objResult.get("stan").getAsString());
            objAuthResponse.setErrorMessage(objResult.get("responseMsg").getAsString());
            objAuthResponse.setStatus(objResult.get("responseCode").getAsString());
            objAuthResponse.setUidNumber(objResult.get("uidNumber").getAsString());
            objAuthResponse.setRrn(objResult.get("rrn").getAsString());
            objAuthResponse.setRdt(objFITransXTRequest.getDt());
        }
        return Response.ok( objAuthentication.authenticate(objFITransXTRequest)).build();
    }
```

Note: I want to return only one status code that is 200 ok.

Comment: If you need to provide some metadata along with the payload then use Response. Also, with Response you can return 200 (status) even if the payload is null.

Comment: Is that  the only difference or anything else?

Comment: Yes, pretty much so you can use either.